# how to impose heatmap on original image in gradcam

Tags: python, keras

when i want to impose the heatmap on the original image by below code, it gives an error as below. i was wonder if someone helps my how to impose heat map on original image

### Error:

TypeError
Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
31
32
---> 33 save_and_display_gradcam(img_path, heatmap)

in save_and_display_gradcam(img, heatmap, cam_path, alpha)
28
29     # Display Grad CAM
---> 30     display(Image(cam_path))
31
32

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Note that the heatmap is taken from last convolution layer of my model and its type is numpy array

```
img_path = '/content/drive/MyDrive/4.png'

def save_and_display_gradcam(img_path, heatmap, cam_path="cam.jpg", alpha=0.4):
    # Load the original image
    img = keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(img_path)
    img = keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(img)

    # Rescale heatmap to a range 0-255
    heatmap = np.uint8(255 * heatmap)

    # Use jet colormap to colorize heatmap
    jet = cm.get_cmap("jet")

    # Use RGB values of the colormap
    jet_colors = jet(np.arange(256))[:, :3]
    jet_heatmap = jet_colors[heatmap]

    # Create an image with RGB colorized heatmap
    jet_heatmap = keras.preprocessing.image.array_to_img(jet_heatmap)
    jet_heatmap = jet_heatmap.resize((img.shape[1], img.shape[0]))
    jet_heatmap = keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(jet_heatmap)

    # Superimpose the heatmap on original image
    superimposed_img = jet_heatmap * alpha + img
    superimposed_img = keras.preprocessing.image.array_to_img(superimposed_img)

    # Save the superimposed image
    superimposed_img.save(cam_path)

    # Display Grad CAM
    display(Image(cam_path))


save_and_display_gradcam(img_path, heatmap)
```

Comment: Are you importing a module named `display` or `Image`?

Comment: yes. i have imported

Comment: I think you should be doing `Image.Image` or `display.display` if so

Comment: i did it and i got this Error: TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: If you made this class, then `__init__`'s first parameter should be `self`, or you are passing it parameters when it doesn't want any

Comment: well, it doesn't want 2 positional ones that is

Comment: i got the code from this link :  https://keras.io/examples/vision/grad_cam/

Comment: Somewhere you are calling a module like a function, you have to look at your imports and find where those names are and check how they are used

Comment: the problem is that when i use the image which is used in original keras code with my model, there is no problem but when i change the image of original keras code to my image it gives that error

Comment: Can you edit in a side by side of that?

Comment: would you give more explanation about what was your meant of "side by side" if it's possible please

Comment: I was wanting to see the code where one image fails versus the second image that passes. What is different with these images? Are they of the same class?